# Issues connecting teradata from python using ODBC drivers

Tags: python, teradata

Connecting teradata from python, I have this error is:

> pyodbc.Error: ('632', '[632] 523 630 (0) (SQLDriverConnect)').

Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: Hi Dhoni Singh, welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll get better responses if your question follows the [guidelines for good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, try to demonstrate what you're doing (a couple of lines of code would be great) and explain what you *think* the error means and what you've tried already.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export ODBCINI to the location of your odbc.ini, e.g.: 
    export ODBCINI=/opt/teradata/client/15.00/odbc_64/odbc.ini